# Unable to generate combination of numbers in python list using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to generate a combination of numbers in python list using recursion
and my code is as follows

```
nums = [2,3,4,6]

def backtrck(temp, starting_index, nums):
    if len(temp) == 2:
        print(temp)
        return
    temp.append(nums[starting_index])
    for i in range(starting_index + 1, len(nums)):
        backtrck(temp, i, nums)

backtrck([], 0, nums)
```

for some reason, the above code is unable to generate the proper combinations.

**Aim of the code:** I want to generate all the combination of numbers starting with index 0 whose length should be equal to 2

**expected output**

```
[2, 3]
[2, 4]
[2, 6]
```

**actual output**

```
[2, 3]
[2, 3]
[2, 3]
[2, 3]
```

I don't understand what is going wrong with this recursion, I am hoping that someone could help me figure this out

Comment: You should be checking several things in your code.Like the `return`, you are not returning anything. Also as the tell you in the answer, if you need a single iteration, not sure what is the point of using recursion

Comment: You should use a debugger or [this site](http://pythontutor.com) to step through your code and observe what it is doing.

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre `return` doesn't need to return anything for it to be used properly. The `return` statement in the function is to stop continuing to parse the loop.

Comment: If you are using an IDE **now** is a good time to learn its debugging features  Or the built-in [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). Printing *stuff* at strategic points in your program can help you trace what is or isn't happening. 
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 3):

Recursion is unnecessary when you can simply use `for` loop:

```
nums = [2,3,4,6]

def backtrck(starting_index, nums):
    start = nums[starting_index]
    for num in nums[starting_index + 1:]:
        print([start, num])
        
backtrck(0, nums)
```

Output:

```
[2, 3]
[2, 4]
[2, 6]
```

where the slice `nums[start_index + 1:]` returns a list of all the elements of the `nums` list starting from one indice after the `starting_index`.

#### UPDATE

Since you've pointed out that the recursion was necessary in your code, simply replace the `backtrck(temp, i, nums)` recursive call with `backtrck(i, nums, [temp[0], nums[i]])` to keep the starting index of the list:

```
nums = [2, 3, 4, 6]

def backtrck(starting_index, nums, temp=[]):
    if len(temp) == 2:
        print(temp)
        return
    temp.append(nums[starting_index])
    for i in range(starting_index + 1, len(nums)):
        backtrck(i, nums, [temp[0], nums[i]])

backtrck(0, nums)
```

Output:

```
[2, 3]
[2, 4]
[2, 6]
```

*Note that I've changed the positional argument `temp` into a keyword argument. It will still work with `temp` as a positional argument, but it will be less practical if the `temp` list always starts out as empty.*

Comment: Thanks for the alternative approach. But the question I asked is a part of a bigger problem that is specifically asked to be solved in recursion. That is the reason I have asked for the recursive approach

Comment: You certainly *made it recursive* but it's kinda *tricky*.  :)

Answer (score 2):

### What is wrong with your function:

After couple of recursive calls `temp` becomes `[2,3]` then on the next recursion your base case is met (`len(temp) == 2:`) and that instance of the function returns without adding anything. The next for loop iteration *recurses* and the same thing happens.  Once `temp` is `[2,3]` it can never change.

### How to fix it:

There are a number of problems with the structure of your function and it is not a simple *one-line-fix*.  You need to figure out how to

- when the base case is met

  - *capture* (or print) `temp`
  - return something meaningful to the previous function that it can use to continue making combinations
- the function needs to act upon the return value from the recursive call
- adding a for loop to a recursive procedure/process complicates things, maybe figure out how to do without it.

I would start over with the function. I don't know if you are asking someone to give you a completely new function so I'm going to search for questions regarding recursive solutions to find/generate list item combinations.

---

Here are some related SO Questions/Answers. If any of them solve your problem let us know so we can mark yours as a duplicate. Most don't have the [*taken two-at-a-time*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) constraint but maybe you can adapt.  there are many more.

[Recursive function that returns combinations of size n chosen from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55877039/recursive-function-that-returns-combinations-of-size-n-chosen-from-list)
[Recursively find all combinations of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65181109/recursively-find-all-combinations-of-list)
[python recursion list combinations without using generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45034279/python-recursion-list-combinations-without-using-generator)
[Using recursion to create a list combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26136673/using-recursion-to-create-a-list-combination)

Loosely related:
[Nth Combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776442/nth-combination)
[Finding all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum)
[Creating all possible k combinations of n items in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991758/creating-all-possible-k-combinations-of-n-items-in-c) - not Python but algorithms might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to recursion, my advice is keep it simple and let the recursion do the work for you:

```
def backtrck(numbers):
    if len(numbers) < 2:
        return []

    first, second, *rest = numbers

    return [[first, second]] + backtrck([first] + rest)

nums = [2, 3, 4, 6]

print(*backtrck(nums), sep='\n')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
[2, 3]
[2, 4]
[2, 6]
>
```